# Problems regarding csv.DictReader

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
list3 = []

with open('**directory**') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        list3.append(row)
```

I'm completely new to data analysis using Python, and require some assistance.

The file I'm accessing contains data from 5 people (CSV file). There are 3 columns - participant number, pre-task Score, and post-task Score.

I'm essentially trying to access this file (using csv.DictReader) and manipulate the data. By this, I mean I want to calculate the difference between the post-task score and pre-task score, for each participant, and print this to the screen.

However, I'm not sure how to do this. I can print each row to the screen, and I can save each row in a list (as I've done above) - but I'm clueless as to how I am to manipulate/deal with this data. I'm wondering if there is something better than the module I'm currently using.

Comment: Are you asking how to add numbers in Python and print the result to the screen?

Comment: Can you give an example of the CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the difference between the second and third columns in a CSV file can be accomplished as follows:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    # skip the header row, remove this next line if there is no header
    next(reader, None)

    for row in reader:
        difference = float(row[2]) - float(row[1])
        print str(difference)
```

Comment: Great. That helps a lot! Is it possible to do a similar thing with rows? (i.e. 1st row, 2nd column - 2nd row, 2nd column)

Comment: In other words, iterate over columns as opposed to rows?